# node.js angular 4 application on heroku not able to find index.html

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku

After run the command > git push heroku master
I am not able to start the application due to an Not found error.

```
 at=info method=GET path="/" host=winpi.herokuapp.com request_id=26ef09fe-0713-4290-b3d7-75ae390decfc fwd="87.196.76.163" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=37ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2017-11-18T01:07:34.416342+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/dist/index.html'
```

So here are my file structure locally:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff      15 Nov 14 23:06 Procfile
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff    1555 Nov 12 17:21 angular-cli.json
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff     501 Nov 18 01:07 app.js
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff     956 Oct  4 00:41 cert.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff     769 Oct  3 19:12 csr.pem
drwxr-xr-x   26 brunolopes  staff     884 Nov 16 07:51 dist
drwxr-xr-x    5 brunolopes  staff     170 Sep 26 00:56 e2e
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff     923 Sep 26 00:56 karma.conf.js
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff     887 Oct  3 19:11 key.pem
drwxr-xr-x  828 brunolopes  staff   28152 Nov 13 23:33 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff    2733 Nov 15 20:57 npm-debug.log
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff  327190 Sep 26 01:21 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff    1772 Nov 17 10:54 package.json
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff    2616 Sep 18 19:21 pom.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff     722 Sep 26 00:56 protractor.conf.js
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff      72 Sep 17 23:34 proxy.conf.json
drwxr-xr-x   14 brunolopes  staff     476 Nov 13 19:21 src
drwxr-xr-x    4 brunolopes  staff     136 Nov 13 23:29 target
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff     363 Sep 26 00:56 tsconfig.json
-rw-r--r--    1 brunolopes  staff    2968 Sep 26 00:56 tslint.json
```

The dist folder contains the index.html:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 brunolopes  staff     3585 Nov 16 07:51 index.html
```

Then the app.js file:

```
let express = require('express');
var app = express();
let server = require('http').Server(app);

var path = require('path');
var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/');
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/dist'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  const index = path.join(__dirname,'../dist/index.html');
  res.sendFile(index);
});

var webapp = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
var port = webapp.address().port;
console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });
```

and the .gitignore file after have removed the /dist folder:

```
See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring 
files.

# compiled output
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings 

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Any clue any it is not finding the index.html on the dist, even after have removed the dist folder from .gitignore, it is not being pushed to heroku, I can see it is added when run the git commit but then not pushed running the git push heroku master, the .gitignore remotely is OK, updated with the right content, in this case without the dist folder on it.

Any point missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Is *dist* in your repo? It's quite often put in .gitignore.

Comment: it was but I removed it, now is not on .gitignore but still doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you commit after removing it in .gitignore, and then push to Heroku again. You have to make sure the dist folder is in the repo, otherwise it will not get pushed Heroku.

Comment: all files are commited too, by running, > git add . and >git commit -m 'another test'

Comment: I have ran the command > heroku run bash and have found that actually the dist folder was not present on the remote side... when I removed it from .gitignore and ran git add . it was added and then commited but for some reason was still ignored and not pushed...

Comment: I solved it but still I was not able to add dist to heroku! dist is not on .gitignore, I can see that all content of dist is added and commited but then is not pushed... So I have made a copy of dist to hdist and commited that one...

Comment: This was solved but not the way I wanted, anyway is working, please check the latest comment